# bash shell prompt does not return (hangs) for about 2 mins after execution of wget

Tags: bash, shell, wget, prompt

wget finishes transferring files in about 10s but gets stuck after the transfer for about 2mins after the transfer before returning to the bash shell. Another user on the same system gets the command prompt quickly after the wget command is executed.

Using CentOS 6.3 Linux. Have not made any changes to the .bashrc files.

Comment: type `set > ${USER}.env.txt` in both environments, move to a common direcotory and then `diff *.env.txt`. You may find some clues there. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is just returning to prompt using :

```
wget url &
```

you will have prompt immediately
I usually use

```
nohup wget url &
```

for getting better result

Comment: There seems to be an underlying problem that should be at least discovered, rather than swept under the rug by backgrounding the delay.

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me
add single quote at the front and the end of URL link can resolve this issue.